# Asterisk Media Bypass

Tags: asterisk

Using `asterisk 11.2` certified or `asterisk 11.6` can we achieve media to flow between the peers rather than the `asterisk core` across all the `NAT` conditions.

i.e : Clients are in different `NAT`

Tried `directrtpsetup=yes` and `auto_force_rport` and `auto-comedia`, it is not working out. Appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking will [`directmedia`](http://asteriskfaqs.org/2012/04/20/asterisk-tips/asterisk-directmedia.html) work over NAT, no it will not.

The SIP signalling that sets up the call is totally separate from the RTP stream that carries the audio. Firewalls don't know how to open up the appropriate ports for RTP because they're dynamically allocated during SIP call setup.

Comment: Any way to achieve media flow between peers across NAT?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.